# HTML5 canvas - How to clear and redraw regions with overlapping entities?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Up until now, I've been clearing/redrawing everything on a single canvas at each animation frame, which is naturally very expensive. I've been leaning towards the idea of using multiple canvases, each representing a different layer in the game, and only redrawing regions of the canvas that have changed. This has the potential to drastically reduce the amount of clearing and redrawing in the game (and subsequently improve performance), however I'm foreseeing a problem to this.

Splitting the game components into layers is fine, however if there is a layer with a group of entities that move around, there will be times when one mobile entity overlaps an immobile one. As the immobile one hasn't changed, it is not scheduled for a redraw. The part of the immobile entity's image that was cleared by the mobile entity's movement then never gets redrawn (see below images).

[image: Frame 1]

*Black stationary background layer + Foreground layer with moving entities. The white entity is moving, but the yellow one isn't.*

[image: Frame 2]

*As the yellow entity isn't moving, it is generally safe to say that the pixels in its region have not changed. However the white entity's movement causes some of those pixels to be cleared.*

**Here are the solutions I have come up with:**

1) Like before, clear and redraw the entire canvas, but only for the layer with moving entities. In my game 1 of 4 layers fits into this category.

2) Calculate when objects overlap, and clear/redraw both regions in these situations.

3) Move the stationary entities temporarily to a background layer and process as normal.

**Comments for each solution:**

1) This solution feels like it will not have enough of a performance gain to warrant the redesign.

2) This feels like a more efficient approach, but still requires testing among all entities to see if their borders collide. If the number of entities is great enough, this would have to be further improved by splitting the canvas into regions and processing each region individually.

3) This approach gives me the desirable result of drawing moving entities over stationary ones, but is it as efficient as solution 2?

Are there any other potentially better solutions?

---

As requested by Blindman67, here is my draw code:

```
Sprite.prototype.draw = function()
{
    if (this.hasImage())
    {
        if (this.opacity == 1)
        {
            this.drawImage()
        }
        else
        {
            game.ctx.globalAlpha = this.opacity;
            this.drawWithTransparency();
            game.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        }
    }
}

Sprite.prototype.drawImage = function()
{
    game.ctx.drawImage(
        this.image, 
        this.position.x, 
        this.position.y, 
        this.image.width, 
        this.image.height
    );
}
```

I clear the canvas once at the beginning of every update.

Comment: Clear and redraw is the best solution. I have never had to use layered canvas/dirty region logic due to performance issues. Why are you having performance problems? Without code it's not possible to know. Dirty region: keep a list of rectangle cleared/dirty, adding rect to cover movement of each item, then clear all rects, then set clip for region, test each entity for overlap of that region draw. Each redraw region added should subdivided any underlying region so list of rects do not overlap, can produce many small regions. Only practical for small item counts

Comment: @Blindman67 I am having some performance issues on older PCs and smartphones which I'd like to improve. Reducing redraws seems to be a common optimization when targeting these devices. As for code, I will add a snippet in OP now

Comment: Sorry I am to busy to write a example of dirty region rendering.

Comment: @Blindman67 No problem